# Why import to hive failed and rejected by table already existed?

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive

I imported a table *employees* from mysql to **hdfs** with no problem;
I imported a different table *dep_emp* to **hive**, also successful;
I double checked that in the hive there are only two tables: myfirsthivetable and dep_emp, there is no *employees*;
I then tried to import the table employees to **hive**, but I got error saying:

```
Output directory hdfs://localhost:9000/user/root/employees already exists
```

here is my import query:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/employees  --username root --P --table employees --hive-import
```

here is my hive query result:
[image]

Can anyone help me on this? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how sqoop imports job works:

sqoop creates/imports data in `tmp` dir which is user's `home` dir(in your case it is `/user/root`) and then copy data to its actual location (i.e., `/home/hive/wearhouse`. This `employees` dir should have exist before you ran import statements. so delete that dir or rename it if its important.

`hadoop fs -rmr /user/root/employees`

OR

`hadoop fs -mv /user/root/employees /user/root/employees_1`

and re-run sqoop command!

Comment: Thank you, before my fully understanding on your explanation, I followed your instruction and here is the result: 
`[root@xie1 sbin]# hadoop fs -mv /home/root/employees /home/root/employees_1
mv: '/home/root/employees_1': No such file or directory
`

Comment: use location of your user home, from error it looks like it is `/user/root/employees` so use `user` instead of `home`

Comment: Yes you are right, it works now. However, this raises another question to me: so it looks like importing to *Hive* actually will use *hdfs* as the staging place and will leave a tmp file in *hdfs*? I don't get it at all.

Comment: sqoop deletes staging dir `/user/root/employees` after copying(sucessfully) to actual hdfs location - it is last stage of sqoop job to clean up staging/tmp files - so now if you try to list the `tmp` staging dir, you won't find it. try `hadoop fs -ls /user/root/employees` - please mark it as answer

Comment: Thank you for explanation. It's much appreciated